# Simple Regex question

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to remove this from a url string
`http://.....?page=1`
I know this doesn't work, but I was wondering how you would do this properly.

`document.URL.replace("?page=[0-9]", "")`

Thanks

Comment: Remove what? Your question is not well stated.

Comment: do you want to remove it, or do you just the want value to do something else with it? and what do you want "http://.....?page=1" literally, the '...' part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want to get rid of the protocol and the querystring. So how about just concatenating the remaining parts?

```
var loc = window.location;

var str = loc.host + loc.pathname + loc.hash;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ng3Z/

---

I'm not entirely certain what the requirements are, but this fairly simple regex works.

```
loc.replace(/https?\:\/\/([^?]+)(\?|$)/,'$1');
```

It may be a naive implementation, but give it a try and see if it fits your need.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ng3Z/1/

Comment: This is the simplest and most robust solution. The hash is probably unnecessary in this particular case though.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but even if for curiosity's sake, I'd like to know how the regex would work.  Thanks!

Comment: @Quick: Yeah, wasn't sure if OP wanted the hash in there, so I thought I'd throw it in.

Comment: @Switz: Is that protocol and a simple `?page=n` all that you want to remove?

Answer (score 2):

`?` is a regex special character. You need to escape it for a literal `?`. Also use [regular expression literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
document.URL.replace(/\?page=[0-9]/, "")
```

Comment: Nope. Just used a sample string to prove it works. You should update your question to be more clear if you want more removed than `?page=#`

Comment: No when I said 'that doesn't work' you had something else written. `\?page=[0-9]` then you changed it to `/\?page=[0-9]/` -- thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @patrick dw is most practical but if you're really curious about a regular expression solution then here is what I would do:

```
var trimUrl = function(s) {
  var r=/^http:\/\/(.*?)\?page=\d+.*$/, m=(""+s).match(r);
  return (m) ? m[1] : s;
}
trimUrl('http://foo.com/?page=123'); // => "foo.com/"
trimUrl('http://foo.com:8080/bar/?page=123'); // => "foo.com:8080/bar/"
trimUrl('foobar'); // => "foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're super close.  To grab the URL use location.href and make sure to escape the question mark.

```
var URL = location.href.replace("\?page=[0-9]", "");
location.href = URL; // and redirect if that's what you intend to do
```

You can also strip all query string parameters:

```
var URL = location.href.replace("\?.*", "");
```